# Run code after state update

Tags: reactjs

I have this function, it's registered on click.

```
 mobileZoomClick () {
    const elem = this.state.scale.carousel
    if (this.state.zoom && elem.scale < 1.1) {
      this.zoomOut()
    }
  }

 <div ref='carousel'
    onClick={this.mobileZoomClick.bind(this)}
    className='carousel' style={this.fullscreen('carousel')}
    test={this.state.carouselTransition === 'transitionEnd' && !this.state.zoom && this.flickity()}
  >
```

I would like to add this.flickity() into the function:

```
 mobileZoomClick () {
    const elem = this.state.scale.carousel
    if (this.state.zoom && elem.scale < 1.1) {
      this.zoomOut()
    }
    if(this.state.carouselTransition === 'transitionEnd' && !this.state.zoom){
      this.flickity()
    }
  }
```

but I need it to be updated on state-change. The current solution technically works but throws an error.

this is how the new states are set (this first one is for checking if certain elements are in a css transition:

```
  transitionState (target) {
    // den här behöver fallback för inte transition
    const done = (e) => {
      this.setState({[stateName]: 'transitionEnd'}, () => {
        this.setState({[stateName]: 'transitionComplete'})
      })
      e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, done)
    }
    const elem = this.refs[target]
    const stateName = target + 'Transition'
    this.setState({[stateName]: 'transitionStarted'})
    elem.addEventListener('transitionend', done)
  }
```

this is for zooming out:
     zoomOut () { this.setState({zoom: false}) }

Comment: What do you mean by `I need it to be updated on state-change`

Comment: Could you post the code that actually updates the state? (I guess that would be the function `zoomOut()`)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri if the state changes so that carouselTransition === 'transitionEnd' && !this.state.zoom i want to run this.flickity.

Comment: @OB3 updated, it's transition state that is the impotant one.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. You're the one who's controlling the state change, and you've got a handler for `transitionend`. Why not do something like `this.setState({[stateName]: 'transitionEnd'}, () => { this.flickity() })`?

Comment: The idea is to use transition-state for a bunch of different targets, only one need `this.flickity()`, but i could put a callback there.